# WebSocket Traffic Encoding (GZip)

Tags: http, websocket, gzip

StackOverflow uses the GZip encoding on all of their pages; the same seems to be true for their websocket traffic since it seems completely obfuscated.

[image]

How/What would they use to achieve this; rather what would I need to do to achieve the same since my websocket server is hosted on its own separate server without IIS etc?

Worth noting too that the `http compression` is not set on their websocket connection request either.

---

Full log screenshot: http://i44.tinypic.com/19s4yr.jpg

Comment: Out of interest, how are you sniffing websocket traffic?  Also, its worth noting that the plain text part of the above message is 19 bytes long so may not actually be obfuscated.

Comment: @simonc I actually only saw it by chance why browsing through the log; ill update the post with a screenshot of what it looks like on fiddler. What could it be then since my websocket traffic is in clear text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to RFC6455, WebSocket payload from client to server MUST be masked, server to client MUST NOT be masked. The masking is done by XORring payload with 32 Bit mask .. the value you see in your log.

There is a WS extension in the cooking that provides frame-based compression (deflate). This has nothing to do with masking. Payload with per-frame-compression active compresses payload, and then masks payload (client to server).

Comment: thanks, mate! could you perhaps point me in the direction of such masking implementation, perhaps on the .net framework? Since the value is masked inbound to the client in my screenshot above, is the SO implementation wrong according to spec?

Comment: The screenshot reads: "68 bytes received from browser .. message masking true". So, if that's browser-to-server masked payload, then it's ok. Should it actually be server-to-client, then it's breaking the spec. The spec is clear about that: MUST NOT.

Comment: The masking algorithm is trivial: payload[i] ^= mask[i % 4], where payload and mask are byte arrays, and i indexes the frame payload.

Comment: Because the string "reputation" is visible, it's obviously not displaying XOR'ed bytes. What I assume is happening is the payload is serialized into a format understood by client/server such as bson.

Comment: Maybe some help for some: http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2012/01/23/writing-your-own-websocket-server/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any gzipping here.  It looks like fiddler has started adding support for websockets but its still a work in progress.

The log shows a connection

...then a first message of 12 bytes (461287-inbox.  The initial bytes 81 8C show a new, complete, text frame with 4 byte mask and 12 bytes of data.  Fiddler correctly decodes this.)

...then a second message of 19 bytes (the bytes 81 93 - 19 bytes into the stream - show a new, complete, text frame with 4 byte mask and 19 bytes of data)

...then a third  message of 19 bytes (the later bytes 81 93 - approx 44 bytes into the stream - show a new, complete, text frame with 4 byte mask and 19 bytes of data)

Comment: thanks, mate. I could show you a log of my websocket implemenation where the full text is seen.

Comment: ah of course, I see that masking is indeed `false` so is indeed just the obfuscation of the payload. http://i43.tinypic.com/2n8tug1.png oh and +1 haha :)