# Compressing a JSON string? (And strings in general)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

How should I go about compressing a very large JSON string to transmit over websockets? (Also later to store in localStorage)

It's already minified, but I need something that can do this: http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/compress/ (I tried poking about in the source there and couldn't figure it out)

Comment: The real question is, why would you send a very large string over websockets, and then store it in localstorage, what's the use case for this, there usually are better ways to store and access data.

Comment: You shouldn't worry about it. Data sent over websockets will be automatically compressed with [`permessage-deflate`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-hybi-permessage-compression-28) extension.

Comment: @adeneo The data I'm transmitting over websockets and the data to store locally are not the same data, I'm just saying I will later also need to compress strings for localstorage.

Comment: @Tresdin any good way to find out what's actually being transmitted over a websocket connection? I'm using the [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) module in node and vanilla websockets in the client.

Comment: why is the first comment always an unimaginative 'why'?

Answer (score 7):

You can compress any kind of binary data (strings, Buffers) with Node.js, no external deps required, using the [zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_examples) module.

You can use either gzip or deflate compression algorithms, depending on your needs.

### Example

*(shamelessly stolen from Node.js' website)*

```
const zlib = require('zlib')
const input = JSON.stringify({ some: 'json-data' })

zlib.deflate(input, (err, buffer) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('u-oh')
  }

  // Send buffer as string to client using my imaginary io object
  io.send(buffer.toString('base64'))
})
```

> **Update:** It might be better to just enable [HTTP compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) on the transport layer instead of compressing and decompressing the data on your own.

Comment: I'll need to decompress that on the client side, does the zlib library also exist in a way that I could include it on the client webpage? And I'll want to compress data coming from the client and heading to the server as well.

Comment: You might try to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gzip-js). I wonder, however - would it not make more sense to just enable gzip compression on the HTTP transport layer, instead of implementing compression at API layer? I have updated the answer with relevant note.

Comment: Not totally sure how I'd do that, I'm using [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) in node and websockets in javascript, all the networking stuff is handled for me haha

Comment: There are extensions for websockets that you could use - see [this SO question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298651/how-does-websocket-compress-messages).