how to properly frame websocket messages in python socket library
I'm building a websocket server in python using socket, it's embedded python that I can't install any packages for. I've gotten as far as handling the handshake and establish a connection. I can get data being sent back and forth from my server and client (a React App), but some of the payloads are too large, batching them up worked but then it was too slow. So I've compressed the data using zlib. Now the issue is it's saying Invalid Websocket Frame. I have tried to condense the code as much as possible to give a server that will run and demonstrate the problem.
I will be honest, I started writing this myself but have used AI for some parts of it, particularly the websocket handshake and framing the message, which I don't fully understand (hence the question), and AI can only get you so far.
So here is my server code, this runs in python 3.9 - 3.11, haven't tried other versions.
import socket
import struct
import base64
import hashlib
import zlib
import logging
import json
from threading import Thread

class WebSocketServer(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.connection = None
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('WebSocketServer')

    def run(self):
        try:
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            sock.bind(('', 5558))
            self.logger.info("Server started, waiting for connections...")
            sock.listen(1)
            while True:
                connection, _ = sock.accept()
                if connection:
                    self.connection = connection
                    self.logger.info("Client connected")
                    Thread(target=self.handle_connection, args=[connection]).start()
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(f'Run error: {e}')
        finally:
            if self.connection:
                self.connection.close()
                self.logger.info('Server socket closed')

    def handle_connection(self, connection):
        try:
            if self.perform_handshake(connection):
                while True:
                    msg = self.receive_message(connection)
                    if msg:
                        self.logger.info(f'Received message: {msg}')
                        # Echo messages back
                        self.send_message(json.dumps(msg))
                    else:
                        break
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(f'Connection error: {e}')
        finally:
            connection.close()
            self.logger.info('Connection closed')

    def perform_handshake(self, connection):
        try:
            self.logger.info("Performing handshake...")
            request = connection.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            self.logger.info(f"Handshake request: {request}")

            headers = self.parse_headers(request)
            websocket_key = headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key']
            websocket_accept = self.generate_accept_key(websocket_key)

            response = (
                'HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n'
                'Upgrade: websocket\r\n'
                'Connection: Upgrade\r\n'
                f'Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {websocket_accept}\r\n\r\n'
            )

            connection.send(response.encode('utf-8'))
            self.logger.info("Handshake response sent")
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(f'Handshake error: {e}')
            return False

    def parse_headers(self, request):
        headers = {}
        lines = request.split('\r\n')
        for line in lines[1:]:
            if line:
                key, value = line.split(': ', 1)
                headers[key] = value
        return headers

    def generate_accept_key(self, websocket_key):
        magic_string = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
        accept_key = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha1((websocket_key + magic_string).encode()).digest()).decode('utf-8')
        return accept_key

    def receive_message(self, connection):
        try:
            data = connection.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                return None

            byte1, byte2 = struct.unpack('BB', data[:2])
            fin = byte1 & 0b10000000
            opcode = byte1 & 0b00001111
            masked = byte2 & 0b10000000
            payload_length = byte2 & 0b01111111

            if masked != 0b10000000:
                self.logger.error('Client data must be masked')
                return None

            if payload_length == 126:
                extended_payload_length = data[2:4]
                payload_length = int.from_bytes(extended_payload_length, byteorder='big')
                masking_key = data[4:8]
                payload_data = data[8:]
            elif payload_length == 127:
                extended_payload_length = data[2:10]
                payload_length = int.from_bytes(extended_payload_length, byteorder='big')
                masking_key = data[10:14]
                payload_data = data[14:]
            else:
                masking_key = data[2:6]
                payload_data = data[6:]

            decoded_bytes = bytearray()
            for i in range(payload_length):
                decoded_bytes.append(payload_data[i] ^ masking_key[i % 4])

            if opcode == 0x1:  # Text frame
                return decoded_bytes.decode('utf-8')
            elif opcode == 0x8:  # Connection close frame
                self.logger.info('Connection closed by client')
                return None
            else:
                self.logger.error(f'Unsupported frame type: {opcode}')
                return None
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(f'Error receiving message: {e}')
            return None

    def send_message(self, message):
        try:
            if self.connection and isinstance(message, str):
                # Compress the message using zlib
                compressed_message = zlib.compress(message.encode('utf-8'))

                # Determine chunk size based on network conditions
                max_chunk_size = 1024  # Adjust as needed

                # Split the compressed message into smaller chunks
                chunks = [compressed_message[i:i+max_chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(compressed_message), max_chunk_size)]

                for chunk in chunks:
                    frame = bytearray()
                    frame.append(0b10000001)  # Text frame opcode

                    length = len(chunk)
                    if length <= 125:
                        frame.append(length)
                    elif length <= 65535:
                        frame.append(126)
                        frame.extend(struct.pack('!H', length))
                    else:
                        frame.append(127)
                        frame.extend(struct.pack('!Q', length))

                    # Append the chunk to the frame
                    frame.extend(chunk)

                    # Send the framed chunk
                    self.connection.sendall(frame)
            else:
                self.logger.error("Connection closed or invalid message")
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error(f'Error sending message: {e}')
            
            
# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Create an instance of WebSocketServer
server = WebSocketServer()

# Start the server
server.start()

And to test it I'm just using wscat from the terminal
wscat -c ws://127.0.0.1:5558

Then I type any message, and the response I get is:
error: Invalid WebSocket frame: invalid UTF-8 sequence

Why am I seeing this error?
How should I be framing these messages?
Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

For context, the payloads I'm sending is an array of arrays of integers, the data is MIDI SysEx, so each array starts with a 0xF0 and ends with an 0xF7 byte. Because of this the messages are getting sent really quickly which is what was causing the problem. The first message is usually going to be quite large and get batched up, so could be thousands of SysEx arrays.
I have sent this data over similar web sockets before so I know it is possible, but I've never had to write them from scratch before.
Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Where is this exception being raised? A stack trace might be helpful.

You cannot just compress content in the server and expect the client to magically know that the content is compressed and how it needs to be decompressed (i.e. algorithm, frame vs. message compression). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298651/how-does-websocket-compress-messages . wscat will assume the frames to contain utf-8 text and fail with the message you got when this expectation is not met by your server.

@SteffenUllrich Thanks, removing the compression does indeed resolve the issue and wscat gets the data echoed back. However I' not able to get ANYTHING to come through at all in the browser so I can't uncompress it. I was trying to uncompress with pako.inflate()

Do not assume recv(n) will receive a complete packet sent. TCP is a byte stream and the receive could be 1-n bytes or 0 on socket close. Check the return value and keep receiving until you have a complete message. Send the size of a message first or use a byte never used in a message to determine a complete message

@jbflow: " I' not able to get ANYTHING to come through at all in the browser" - do you mean that you cannot get anything in the browser with compression in your code removed? Or that you cannot get anything with compression enabled? And what does your statement actually mean - that you got no websocket frames from the server, that you cannot decompress these, that you get errors in the developer console, ... ?

@SteffenUllrich Apologies for the lack of clarity, yes what was happening was no websocket frames were coming through in the browser because of how I set up the websocket. thank you @MarkTolonen for your comment, both comments have directed me to the solution I now have. Which was to set the opcode to binary instead of text so that I could send compressed data and also setting the websocket.bufferType = "arrayBufferr" in the client.

I have found the solution to my problem so will answer it here.
Thanks to both @SteffenUllrich @MarkTolonen for their guidance above.
As @SteffenUllrich stated my client was expecting text data and I am sending compressed binary data, so I needed to use the binary frame opcode instead of text.
This line inside of the send_message function
frame.append(0b10000010)  # Binary frame opcode

Instead of
frame.append(0b10000001)  # Text frame opcode

This allows the data to come through into wscat and works fine, but I wasn't seeing it in the browser. So I needed to set the following in my React App to allow it to accept binary data.
websocket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';

Additional reading that I found that helped me understand what's going on can be found here
