# Manually GZIP data over websocket?

Tags: sockets, scala, compression, gzip

I have a web socket proxy that accepts messages and passes them through to clients (browser and Flash).

In an attempt to optimize I was hoping to GZIP the data that goes over that web socket connection.  Is this possible, and/or what are the other approaches that might work for this?

I know that there is a WebSocket extension being worked on according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646680/could-websocket-support-gzip-compression) StockOverflow question.

My current approach within a Scala/Jetty application:

```
def compressBytes(bytes:Array[Byte]) = {
    val bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
    val gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bos)
    gzip.write(bytes)
    gzip.close
    bos.toByteArray
  }

sent to the client:

def onMessage(bytes:Array[Byte], offset:Int, length:Int) {
  serverSocket.connection.sendMessage(compressBytes(bytes), offset, length)
}
```

Side note:  I know that the [Sec-WebSocket-Extensions](http://www.igvita.com/2013/11/27/configuring-and-optimizing-websocket-compression/): permessage-deflate is a possibility, but not yet full adopted (Jetty 9 has it I believe)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With jetty, you can just drop in a servlet filter to do the job: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/gzip-filter.html

Comment: Thanks, I have dropped that filter in, but I didn't see any difference in the message size (wiresshark/tcpdump).  Then I thought I might need to pass something in the websocket handshake (accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, or the Sec-WebSockets-Extensions header).  Any thoughts on how to force Jetty to gzip the web socket traffic?

Comment: Filter is <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>mimeTypes</param-name>
            <param-value>text/html,text/plain,text/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/css,application/javascript,image/svg+xml</param-value>
        </init-param>