# GZIP traffic via websockets

Tags: websocket, socket.io, gzip

Is it possible to pack and unpack websockets traffic frame by frame with GZIP?

We have a lot of websockets traff (real time quotes) that should be packed to reduce traffic, but I have no idea if it is even possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could websocket support gzip compression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646680/could-websocket-support-gzip-compression)

Comment: I saw that question, but there is no answer.
Proposition was submitted a YEAR ago to IETF but what happened since then?

Comment: you can deflate and base64 worst-case... js has lots of inflate()/deflate() tools available. You could also consider using CSV instead of JSON, which can reduce typical data object footprints a lot (no quotes, no key repeats). It recently saved me ~75% pushing calendar entries, where deflate yielded about 85% reduction on the same JSON. Considering that CSV is faster to build and unpack, i can live with that...

Answer (score 3):

Per-message compression as per [this draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-permessage-compression-16) is where things are going.

Browser support still stands at Chrome-only. Webkit seems to be in the works, but there is no telling when FF and IE will follow.

On the server side, there is e.g. an implementation of this in [AutobahnPython](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython) (see [example here](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_compressed)).

Depending on what stack/environments you use for your project, this means that you can try WebSocket compression today.

(Full disclosure: I work for Tavendo, the project maintainer for the Autobahn WebSockets projects.)

Answer (score 0):

I use LZ-String to encode/decode JSON back and forth through sockets; a really slick JavaScript implementation of LZW compression.

Until people reach a standard on this, it's a great solution.

http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html

It reduces text bandwidth an average of 10x and takes less than 1ms to decode a few kb.